# Show all Flows Attached/Triggered by a SharePoint Online List

Tags: sharepoint-online, administration, flow

We're looking for a way to identify any Flows that are connected to specific SharePoint Online lists. We do have access to Flow Admin Center, but there doesn't seem to be a way to filter the Flows to ones connected with a specific list.

Comment: I used the same code, but always it return empty response {"value":[]}, but i have multiple flows for that SharePoint list var _credencials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("admin@tenant.onmicrosoft.com", passsecureobject); using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/site1/")) { clientContext.Credentials = _credencials; List list = clientContext.Web.GetList("https://tanant.sharepoint.com/sites/site1/Lists/Countries"); clientContext.Load(list); clientContext.ExecuteQuery(); var flows = list.SyncFlowInstances(); //var flows = list.SyncFlowInstance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to access details about flows attached to the list using the CSOM. Here is a sample code that can be used for that:

```
//You need to connect to the site using CSOM, and then you can use this code to get the flows details
//...    
List list = context.Web.GetList("Lists/YourList");
var flows = list.SyncFlowInstances();
context.Load(flows);
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

`flows.SynchronizationData` contains the JSON string with all the details about flows.
You can either get the details about flows manualy from the flows.SynchronizationData string or by deserializing it and looping through all the flows.
One way to access it would be by using System.Web.Helpers assembly, like this:

```
using System.Web.Helpers;

//...

List list = context.Web.GetList("Lists/YourList");
var flows = list.SyncFlowInstances();
context.Load(flows);
context.ExecuteQuery();

dynamic data = Json.Decode(flows.SynchronizationData);
for(var i = 0; i < data.value.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(data.value[i].properties.displayName);
}
```

Comment: This was an excellent approach, thanks. System.Web.Helpers was not available in .NET 4.7, but adding microsoft-web-helpers from Nuget resolved that.

Comment: I tries the above code but all I am able to get from SynchronizationData is '{"value":[]}'. I am on .Net framework 4.5.2 have SCA access on the site and owner of the flow

Answer (score 0):

Very interesting question -  to achieve this you can write a MS Flow with the action "List Flows as Admin" this will return you all Flow from your environment, then at the end of this we can export the results to csv or we can add the result to SharePoint custom list, from their we can filter by list name.... and also you may seek for similar kind of "List Flows as Admin" action which will get the flow by list.... though I have not checked this :-)  may be something ready-made could be available.

Reference URL :
https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/How-to-get-a-list-of-all-flows-in-environment/td-p/292002