# Find which Flow (Power Automate) is connected to my SPO List

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow, power-automate

We have a number of Lists & Libraries in SharePoint Online, and a number of Power Automate Flows that were created by another team (they don't work with us anymore). The names given to those Flows are a bit cryptic and there's hundreds of them. So now the question is- how do I find out which Flow is connected to which List or Library? I don't want to open each and every Flow manually. Thought there must be a better way to find this out? Also, how can I take ownership of those Flows (once I find the relevant ones)?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no OOB solution to get the Flow associations with SharePoint lists.
You will have to consider custom solutions, for example, [access details about flows attached to the list using the CSOM](https://collab365.community/get-list-flow-instances-attached-sharepoint-list/).

Another reference: [Show all Flows Attached/Triggered by a SharePoint Online List.](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/271804/show-all-flows-attached-triggered-by-a-sharepoint-online-list)

Also, you won’t be able to run the flows unless they are shared with you. So there is no really a way to take ownership, the owner has to [add your account as an extra owner](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/create-team-flows#add-an-owner-to-a-flow).

Reference: [How to find out what are the flows attached to a list not created by me?](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Power-Automate/How-to-find-out-what-are-the-flows-attached-to-a-list-not/td-p/70412)